# Need to eliminate one .click() event

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is for a working model of a knee. In order to load each view of the knee dynamically, and get rid of the hash in my URL, I used the pushState method, which includes a `.click()` event. So basically i have two categories, and when you click on one of the options from the categories, the application loads a description of that part of the knee. But for some reason, i can click the category, which loads dynamically, but when I click one of the options in the category, the page refreshes. After that refresh, each option in the category loads dynamically. I'm wondering if my `.click()` events are clashing, or possibly causing a refresh for some reason. And if they are, I need to be able to join the two in one function without disrupting the pushState method. Any thoughts? Here's the code I think may be clashing:

```
$(function() {
    $('.knee-navigation a').click(function() {
        $('.knee-navigation a').removeClass();
        $(this).addClass('current_cat');


        if ($('.maladies-label a').hasClass('current_cat')) {
            $(".term-list").load("maladies-menu.php ul");
        } else {
            $(".term-list").load("anatomy-menu.php ul");
        }
    });
});




$(function() {
    var main = $("main");

    $("a, area").click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");

        history.pushState('', '', href);

        // load the content
        loadContent(href);

        return false;
    });

});
```

Help!

Comment: `.unbind('click')` : see http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default action for some elements (eg: `button', 'a', etc) cause the page to go elsewhere.  You can prevent this by making your handlers`preventDefault`on the`event` object, like so:

```
$('a, area').on('click', function (e) {
    // do stuffs

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  If that solved your problem, feel free to accept my answer so other users can see.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to remove the click event from a given element you can use jQuery's `unbind` function (https://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

It would look like this:

```
$("a, area").unbind("click");
```